# In Java, is there a cleaner approach to an if statement with a slew of ||'s

Tags: java

I know this question is basic but I am looking for a less-clumsy approach to the following if statement:

```
if ((sOne.Contains('*')) || (sOne.Contains('/')) || (sOne.Contains('-')) || (sOne.Contains('+')) || (sOne.Contains('%'))){
```

I should also note that `sOne.Contains()` refers to the following code...

```
public boolean Contains(char key) {
    // Checks stack for key
    boolean retval = arrs.contains(key);
    return retval;

}
```

It should also be noted that those five chars will never be changed.

Comment: Maybe having those chars in an array and that contains function receives an array instead of just one key. Just an idea

Comment: @KenHall Even though it has been a while, the community would appreciate it if you accepted an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a breaking for-each loop over a character array:

```
for (char c : "*/-+%".toCharArray()) {
    if (sOne.Contains(c)) {
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

If you're extremely concerned about performance you might also want to pull out the `toCharArray()` call and cache the result in a `static final char[]` constant.

You could even use this strategy to define other convenience methods on your `sOne` object, like `ContainsAny` or `ContainsAll` (credit to [Sina Madrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42882122/7256039) for the name `ContainsAny`):

```
public boolean ContainsAny (CharSequence keys) {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        if (Contains(keys.charAt(i)) return true;

    return false;
}

public boolean ContainsAll (CharSequence keys) {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        if (!Contains(keys.charAt(i)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Usage would look something like this:

```
if (sOne.ContainsAny("*/-+%")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using regular expression like this

```
if (sOne.matches(".*[-*/+%].*")) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: I don't think `sOne` is a `String`.

Comment: @gyre  You are right, but looks like I am not the only who got confused, but well, a clean answer nonetheless

Comment: This answer is useless for the OP. If `sOne` was a `String`, a cleaner approach would be pre-compiling the `Pattern` "[-*/+%]" and then calling `find()` instead of `matches()` on the `Matcher`.

Comment: @xehpuk wut? Did you **ever** read the API doc for `String.matches()`

Comment: If so, I don't understand why you said `Compiling Pattern "[-*/+%]" and then calling find() instead of matches() on the Matcher.` is better than just using `String.matches` because `String.matches` achieves the same goal with less code

Comment: Performance for two reasons. First: "If a pattern is to be used multiple times, compiling it once and reusing it will be more efficient than invoking this method each time." (from [Pattern.matches(regex, str)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-)) Second: Trying to find a whole match on `".*[-*/+%].*"` is more expensive than finding a sub-match on `"[-*/+%]"`.

Comment: Oh gee, I think you didn't grasp what I meant by "clean answer". I didn't say fast performant code

Comment: Well, this is not code-golf, so shortest answer is usually not the best. Or what do you think is clean about this answer?

Comment: @xehpuk I suggest you read Robert C. Martin's book "Clean Code" to get a grib on what "clean" means in writing code because you do not seem to understand the word in this context at all

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere, you need the characters in a list:

```
List<Character> keys = Arrays.asList('*', '/', '-', '+', '%');
```

And then you can do:

```
if (keys.stream().anyMatch(sOne::Contains)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this method:
Items are your keys stored in an Array.

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items)
{
    for(int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputStr.contains(items[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what **arr** is but since it has a **contains** method I'm going to assume it is a collection.  So if you were to put your keys into a static collection like a Set and if **arr** is a collection of some type as well, you could use **Collections.disjoint**.  **disjoint** returns true if there is no intersection between two collections.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
  static Set<Character> keys = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('*','/','-','+','%'));

  static class SOne {
    Set<Character> arrs = null;
    SOne(String line) {
      arrs = line.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    public boolean Contains(Set<Character> checkset) {
      return !Collections.disjoint(arrs, checkset);
    }
  }

  static public void main(String args[]) {
    SOne sOne = new SOne("Does not contain");
    SOne sTwo = new SOne("Does contain a + sign");

    if(sOne.Contains(keys)) {
      System.out.println("Fail: Contains a key");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Pass: Does not contain a key");
    }

    if(sTwo.Contains(keys)) {
      System.out.println("Pass: Contains a key");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Fail: Does not contain a key");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, arrs is an ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method like this and still re-use your existing method (substitute T for type of sOne):

```
static <T> boolean ContainsAny(T sOne, char... keys) {
    for (char key : keys) {
        if (sOne.Contains(key))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then invoke it like so with any number of characters to evaluate:

```
if (ContainsAny(sOne, '%', '_', '-')) {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `if` statement of this form in only one place, it would be fine to keep the same structure but just format it more neatly:

```
if (sOne.contains('+') ||
    sOne.contains('-') ||
    sOne.contains('*') ||
    sOne.contains('/') ||
    sOne.contains('%')) {
    ...
}
```

P.S. In your method it is not necessary to define a `boolean` variable merely to immediately return it; you can return the other method's result directly:

```
public boolean contains(char key) {
    // Checks stack for key
    return arrs.contains(key);
}
```

Please also note the naming conventions: method names (`contains`) should start with a lower-case letter.